# Отправка GET запроса из Android приложения

Tags: java, android

Стоит задача, чтобы отправить на сервер запрос и получить с него ответ в виду json.
Пытался найти информацию в интернете, но попадались лишь готовые решения, без какого-либо объяснения.

Можете подсказать с объяснением, как правильно сделать подобный запрос на сервер? Желательно, с дальнейшим чтением json.

Comment: Я могу подсказать прочитать любой учебник по android-разработке.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте добавил в вопрос больше конкретики, советовать не зная что вы нашли в сети довольно сложно, добавьте в вопрос то что вы нашли, какие технологии и библиотеки видели что вам было не понятно и тп.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рекомендую научиться использовать связку Retrofit2 + RxJava2.
Для начала потребуются следующие зависимости

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:?.?.?'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:?.?.?'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:?.?.?'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:?.?.?'
```

Создаем модель. Собственно это данные которые нам и нужны
В данной связке Ответ будет автоматически разобран согласно модели.

```
public class User {
  @SerializedName("login")  \\Имя соответствует такому в json
  String login;

  @SerializedName("id")
  Integer id;

  @SerializedName("node_id")
  String nodeId;

  @SerializedName("avatar_url")
  String avatarUrl;

  @SerializedName("gravatar_id")
  String gravatarId;

  @SerializedName("url")
  String url;

  @SerializedName("html_url")
  String htmlUrl;
```

1) Создаем API

```
public interface GithubApi {
  @GET("users")
  Single<List<User>> getUsers(@Query("since") Integer since);
  // Если не использовать RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
  //  @GET("users")
  //  Call<List<User>> getMyUsers();
```

2) Создаем сервис

```
public class MyService {

  //  Создаем переменную API и BASE_URL
  private static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/";
  private GithubApi githubApi;

  //  Создаем конструктор
  public MyService() {
    Retrofit retrofit =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            //  body (String) будет кастоваться к объектам через Gson
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            //  Вместо Call будет использоваться RxJava объекты Observable или Single
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();

    //  Инициализируем переменную через ретрофит.
    githubApi = retrofit.create(GithubApi.class);
  }

  public Single<List<User>> userRequest(Integer since) {
    return githubApi.getUsers(since);
  }
 // Если не использовать RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
 //  public Call<List<User>> getMyUsers() {
 //    return githubApi.getMyUsers();
 //  }
}
```

3) Создаем презентер

```
public class MainPresenter {

  MyService myService;
  Listener listener;
  CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

  MainPresenter(Listener listener) {
    this.myService = new MyService();
    this.listener = listener;
  }

  public void userRequest(Integer since) {
    disposable.add(
        myService
            .userRequest(since)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                users -> {
                  listener.usersReceived(users);
                },
                throwable -> {
                  throwable.printStackTrace();
                }));

    // Если не использовать RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
    //    myService.getMyUsers().enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
    //      @Override
    //      public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> 
    //      response) {
    //
    //      }
    //
    //      @Override
    //      public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
    //
    //      }
    //    });
  }

  public void clearDisposables() {
    if (!disposable.isDisposed()) {
      disposable.dispose();
    }
  }

  public interface Listener {
    void usersReceived(List<User> users);
  }
}
```

4) В активити или фрагменте вызываем так

```
mainPresenter =
    new MainPresenter(
        new MainPresenter.Listener() {
          @Override
          public void usersReceived(List<User> users) {
            // Здесь реагируем на получение данных и что угодно с ними делаем.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), new Gson().toJson(users), 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
          }
        });
```

Comment: Поставил + вам за ответ, но человеку для начала теорию узнать, а фреймворки уже потом использовать чтобы понимать самому, а вы его как обудохом по голове, потом вырастаю "Фреймворк программисты"